# Postgres JDBC FDW Ubuntu 14 install error: Makefile:53: ../../src/Makefile.global: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden

Tags: jdbc, ubuntu-14.04, postgresql-9.3, postgres-fdw

I tried both JDBC FDWs (*jdbc* (atris) and *jdbc2* (heimir sverrisson)) mentioned on the [FDW wiki page](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Foreign_data_wrappers#Generic_SQL_Database_Wrappers) and following the [source install instructions](https://github.com/atris/JDBC_FDW/wiki/Installation-instructions), but always get this error:

```
root@...:/usr/share/postgresql/9.3/contrib/jdbc2_fdw-master# make clean
Makefile:53: ../../src/Makefile.global: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
Makefile:54: /contrib/contrib-global.mk: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
make: *** Keine Regel, um »/contrib/contrib-global.mk« zu erstellen.  Schluss.
```

Running Ubuntu `14.04.3 LTS`:

```
# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
Release:        14.04
Codename:       trusty
```

the `Makefile.global` can be found in the `/usr/lib` folder:

```
# locate Makefile.global
/usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/lib/pgxs/src/Makefile.global
```

I adjusted the `Makefile` regarding the relative path inside to point there, but then the second error remains and `contrib-global.mk` can't be located :-/

I'll continue to try the *MySQL* FDW, but since we already use a buggy *Oracle* FDW it would have been nice to stick to some generic JDBC driver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following command:

```
PATH=/usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/bin/:$PATH make USE_PGXS=1 clean
```

It works for me.

Comment: Thx. I'll test it later when I am back working on the related project again - which can take some weeks.

Comment: did not have time to check, but trusting it works in this case I'll mark it as acceppted :)